# How to find the "real" error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am having an enormous amount of errors showing up in the error list of the program, but none of the ones listed seem to be "real" errors. Some of the lines are red and then when I go to highlight over them the error disappears. I just can't seem to find where my error really is. What is the best process to go through to find my mistake?

Below is the error list in case that is helpful.

```
    Error   38  error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found   85
Error   68  error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found   42
Error   63  error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping    compilation  72
Error   66  error C2059: syntax error : ')' 42
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : '>' 80
Error   40  error C2059: syntax error : '>' 80
Error   65  error C2059: syntax error : '>' 42
Error   20  error C2065: '_Ptr_cerr' : undeclared identifier    27
Error   16  error C2065: '_Ptr_cin' : undeclared identifier 25
Error   22  error C2065: '_Ptr_clog' : undeclared identifier    28
Error   18  error C2065: '_Ptr_cout' : undeclared identifier    26
Error   28  error C2065: '_Ptr_wcerr' : undeclared identifier   32
Error   24  error C2065: '_Ptr_wcin' : undeclared identifier    30
Error   30  error C2065: '_Ptr_wclog' : undeclared identifier   33
Error   26  error C2065: '_Ptr_wcout' : undeclared identifier   31
Error   4   error C2065: 'faction' : undeclared identifier  84
Error   42  error C2065: 'faction' : undeclared identifier  84
Error   64  error C2065: 'Faction' : undeclared identifier  42
Error   13  error C2065: 'socialite' : undeclared identifier    100
Error   51  error C2065: 'socialite' : undeclared identifier    100
Error   1   error C2065: 'Socialite' : undeclared identifier    80
Error   12  error C2065: 'Socialite' : undeclared identifier    100
Error   39  error C2065: 'Socialite' : undeclared identifier    80
Error   50  error C2065: 'Socialite' : undeclared identifier    100
Error   8   error C2065: 'textWriter' : undeclared identifier   82
Error   46  error C2065: 'textWriter' : undeclared identifier   82
Error   6   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'  84
Error   10  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'  82
Error   14  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'  100
Error   44  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'  84
Error   48  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'  82
Error   52  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ')'  100
Error   17  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  25
Error   19  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  26
Error   21  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  27
Error   23  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  28
Error   25  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  30
Error   27  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  31
Error   29  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  32
Error   31  error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ';'  33
Error   7   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  32
Error   15  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  10
Error   32  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  36
Error   35  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  27
Error   45  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  32
Error   54  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  34
Error   57  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  48
Error   60  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'  61
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  82
Error   11  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  98
Error   33  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  42
Error   34  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  45
Error   36  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  83
Error   37  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  85
Error   41  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  82
Error   49  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  98
Error   55  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  43
Error   58  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  57
Error   61  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  69
Error   67  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'  42
Error   5   error C2275: 'Faction' : illegal use of this type as an expression  84
Error   43  error C2275: 'Faction' : illegal use of this type as an expression  84
Error   9   error C2275: 'std::ofstream' : illegal use of this type as an expression    82
Error   47  error C2275: 'std::ofstream' : illegal use of this type as an expression    82
Error   53  error C2653: 'Socialite' : is not a class or namespace name 33
Error   56  error C2653: 'Socialite' : is not a class or namespace name 46
Error   59  error C2653: 'Socialite' : is not a class or namespace name 60
Error   62  error C2653: 'Socialite' : is not a class or namespace name 72
```

Comment: Always work top-down - any 'consequential errors' disappear automatically once the original parsing problem is fixed. The first is **always** a real error. If there appears to be no logic involved, restart Visual Studio and don't be surprised if it's fixed - the internal caches might be borked.

Comment: How do I determine the actual first error, which sorting do I use in the error list. This is for visual studios 2010 express.

Comment: I am going to guess at some unterminated construct, such as a #ifdef(XYZ) without a corresponding #endif later in the same file.  Or an opening brace without corresponding closing brace.

Comment: **Hint**: find the lowest-numbered line for which an error is reported and work backwards from that. And since some compilers actually can pinpoint the line where parsing went awry fairly accurately, be sure to look at your output carefully.

Comment: Most of the first errors are apparently located in <iostream>, which doesn't entirely make much sense to me.

Comment: I'm working as professional C++ developer for +20 years, and such situations still might bite me hard. Especially if I'm going to code larger constructs just away, without frequent recompiling. The only recommendation is to recompile as often as possible, at least after you have a 1st compilable skeleton. It was, is, and always will be (hmm, some compilers look promising) hard to track down this kind of error messages (template error messages are similar sometimes), period!

Comment: When you're in primary development mode sort errors by the ID column. Type sorting is only good for warnings or when you tuned the error settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably a missing ; after the closing } of a class / struct. Could you post some code?

UPDATE: The code compiles now on my gcc. The problem I found is that you have a circular dependency between your classes. So solve this, forward declare some of them in the headers. I added `class Faction;` before `class Socialite` in `Socialite.h` and  `class Socialite;` before `class Faction` in `Faction.h`.

Comment: Do I just add it to the original post? There are 7 total files not sure how to post them all.

Comment: Or on pastebin for example

Comment: Could you please also upload list.h

Comment: It is a header file that was given to us to work with to complete the program. Here is the updated pastebin. http://pastebin.com/VUyPwfHE

Comment: Wow I would I have never been able to figure that out. I don't recall anything like this being mentioned in the course notes. Thanks a lot. How would I recognize this type of error in the future?

Comment: My compiler gave me the following errors `Socialite.h:24 'Faction' was not declared in this scope` and `Socialite.h:24 template argument 1 is invalid`. And I had seen such problems before :-)

Comment: I guess next time I have another thing like this running the code in another compiler might be helpful. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @The_Guest Yes, [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) seems to do a good job on this. But it might be still hard to extract the relevant stuff from the target build environment for checking, or to change the current toolchain to clang :-(.

Answer (score 1):

Unexpected end of file is usually that you are missing a closing "something", such as a bracket `}` or parenthesis `)`

Answer (score 0):

It's either a missing `#endif` or a `;` at the end of a type definition or possibly a missing `}` at the end of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the first error reported.  Often it's the cause of a lot of the subsequent problems because the first error causes the parser to be out of sync with the rest of the code.

In C++, long cascades of errors are often caused by an undeclared type (did you forget an include file?) or by a missing `;` after a class or struct definition.

Consider:

```
Foobar fb;  // Declare an instance of Foobar.
```

If Foobar hasn't been declared yet (perhaps because you forgot to include "foobar.h"), then the compiler might think you're trying to declare a variable named Foobar with a default type of int.  From there, it sees the fb and gets all confused.

Or consider:

```
struct Foobar {
  int x;
  int y;
}

int blah = 0;
```

Without the `;` after the struct definition, the parser thinks you're trying to declare an instance of Foobar named int, which isn't allowed since int is a reserved keyword.  And everything after that looks like gobbledegook to the compiler.

One trick is to temporarily `#if 0`-out all the code after the line with the first reported error, as that will reduce the noise until you isolate the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the **"Error List" window** (View > Error List) it can be really hard to figure out where the errors originate. Luckily, there's another way:

1. Open the **"Output" window** (Debug > Windows > Output)
2. Compile and build
3. Start at the top of the **"Output" window** and work your way down the compiler/linker output text until you come to the first line that says "error"

This will usually lead you right to the problem.